# MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine

Tags: flutter

Getting an error at the statement `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);`:

> Error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
>
> [image: GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);]

flutter doctor --verbose output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1158], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at E:\Flutter Projects\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (2 months ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Ariba Khan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.9.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Redmi 5 Plus • c914ce470904 • android-arm64 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50457#issuecomment-584198839 let me know if it works

Comment: @LoVe I have already tried that, did not work.